Airflow - How to input task dependency dynamically?
I am reading some configs and creating tasks dynamically.
Let's say I read config ['carrot', 'apple', 'tomato', 'potato'] and I created four tasks, one for each element in the config.
task1 for carrot, task2 for apple, task3 for tomato and task4 for potato. I am able to do this successfully.
I want to input the task dependency from the user. For example, instead of hard-coding in my DAG code something like:
task1 >> task3
task1 >> task2
[task1, task3] >> task4

I want to input from the user some representation of task dependencies, perhaps a dict and set it dynamically.
So, if I can input a dependency dict like:
{'task3': 'task1', 'task2': 'task1', 'task4':['task1', 'task3']}

How can I set the dependency using bit-shift operator or functions like set_upstream() dynamically?
